# When is the autorelease object released?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autorelease, nsautoreleasepool

I tested it with the following code,and I found that the autorelease objc never release.

```
__weak id ref;

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"test"]; // add autoreleasePool
    ref = str;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"viewWillAppear:%@",ref); // result test
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"viewDidAppear:%@",ref); // result test
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"%@",ref); // If I click long after，But it has not been released
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`[NSString stringWithFormat:]` doesn't promise you an object on the autoreleasepool. It promises you an object that you do not have to release. In this case, it's returning you a constant string, and a constant string is never destroyed. It is also free to return you a cached value, or a value shared with other readers, a tagged pointer, or a singleton. NSNumber has lots of optimizations like this.

To the underlying question, when the local autorelease pool is drained, one `release` will be sent to the object for each `autorelease` that was previously sent to the object on that pool. Whether this destroys the object or not depends on what other retains have been placed on it.

I would expect a value like this to behave closer to what you're expecting, but there are no promises:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"something a little long and computed: %d", rand()]
```

Comment: Note also that, under ARC, the retain/release/autorelease semantics can change at whim of compiler.  It is quite likely that you'll see more autorelease traffic in debug builds vs. release builds, for example.

Comment: Under MRC,When is the autorelease object released?I know that the autorelease object in the runloop iteration ends.And I was wondering that If I call the autorelease object after 10min,I think the runloop has been iterated many times.So the autorelease object has been released.But I tried it and found the result was not what I expected.

Comment: With MRC, it's as I was saying above "when the local autorelease pool is drained, one release will be sent to the object for each autorelease that was previously sent to the object on that pool." And yes, there is an autorelease pool that is drained at the end of every runloop. But everything I've said here applies to MRC (it applies to MRC *more* than it applies to ARC). There is no promise that the returned value of `stringWithFormat:` is "an autoreleased object." There is just a promise that you don't have to release it.

Comment: Also, even an object with autorelease on it may not be destroyed when the pool drains. It is promised to have `release` sent to it. That may not destroy the object.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I understand.